# Counting full, case insensitive words using scrapy and regular expression

Tags: regex, scrapy, case-insensitive, word-boundaries

I am using a scrapy crawl spider to count the number of instances of specific words on each page in a domain. So far, my code is generally successful in doing so, but **I would like it to be case insensitive and to only count full words**. For example, if I am counting the number of times 'demo' appears, I would like it to also count 'Demo' and 'DEMO' but not 'democracy'. Here is what I have so far:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
         yield{
             'demo': len(response.css('body').re('demo')),
             }
```

For the case sensitivity issue, I have found advice that suggests using xpath's translate or re.ignorecase. For the full words only issue, I have found advice on using word boundaries. However, I am not sure how to incorporate any of them in this situation. I have tried and failed a number of times.

### Edit

The following fix solves the problem:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
         yield{
             'demo': len(response.css('body').re(r'(?i)\bdemo\b')),
             }
```

Comment: If you wish to ignore things like `<div class="demo">` then you need to target just the `text()` nodes using xPath and apply regex `\bdemo\b` using the `re.IGNORECASE` flag. If `re.IGNORECASE` is not available then `(?i)\bdemo\b` should work.

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus. I have tried the following `'demo': len(response.xpath('//body/text()').re('(?i)\bdemo\b'))` but it returns an output of zero, although I know there are 6 instances in my text. The same happens with `'demo': len(response.xpath('//body/text()').re('demo'))`. Is there an issue with the code?